# Not able to parse json in python , but able to view the text in json viewer

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am trying to parse the following json text in python but I am getting error, 
Although I am able to parse this json text using a [Json Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) . So I guess my json text is correct , Can someone please help me what is wrong here ?

```
import json as j

data = '{"c":[{"xy":{"xstart":0,"xend":5,"ystart":1,"yend":5},"names":["D","T","O","H","L","C",],"co":["rgb(0,0,128)"]}],"Values":{"D":["11/30/2012"],"T":["09:44:00"],"O":["5848.40"],"H":["5848.40"],"L":["5847.45"],"C":["5848.40"]}}'
json_data = j.loads(data)
#print json_data["c"][0]



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:json\jsonexample.py", line 4, in <module>
    json_data = j.loads(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: Because this website is not very smart... It is loading JSON with `eval` instead of `JSON.parse`. If you cannot fix the input, try a YAML parser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it is a problem with your actual string. This line:

```
"names":["D","T","O","H","L","C",]
```

Has an extra comma after the `"C"`. Try removing that and see if it works as expected.

```
In [1]: import json as j

In [2]: data = '{"c":[{"xy":{"xstart":0,"xend":5,"ystart":1,"yend":5},"names":["D","T","O","H","L","C"],"co":["rgb(0,0,128)"]}],"Values":{"D":["11/30/2012"],"T":["09:44:00"],"O":["5848.40"],"H":["5848.40"],"L":["5847.45"],"C":["5848.40"]}}'

In [3]: json_data = j.loads(data)

In [4]: json_data['c'][0]
Out[4]:
{u'co': [u'rgb(0,0,128)'],
 u'names': [u'D', u'T', u'O', u'H', u'L', u'C'],
 u'xy': {u'xend': 5, u'xstart': 0, u'yend': 5, u'ystart': 1}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah found two occurrences with extra comma.